# undefined is not a function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to implement an alphabetical searching in my datatables, I found that the below function which is responsible for filtering is not working properly. I am not getting that alert.I have googled the codes and found that the codes are alright.But still it does not work. Ask me if anybody needs full code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var table = $('#datatables').DataTable();

    var alphabet = $('<div class="alphabet"/>').append( 'Search: ' );


    $('<span class="clear active"/>')
        .data( 'letter', '' )
        .html( 'None' )
        .appendTo( alphabet );

    for ( var i=0 ; i<26 ; i++ ) {

        var letter = String.fromCharCode( 65 + i );

        $('<span/>')
            .data( 'letter', letter )
            .html( letter )
            .appendTo( alphabet );
    }

    alphabet.insertBefore( table.table().container() );

    alphabet.on( 'click', 'span', function () {


        alphabet.find( '.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );

        $(this).addClass( 'active' );

        _alphabetSearch = $(this).data('letter');

        table.draw();

    } );

});


var _alphabetSearch = '';


    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings,data,dataindex) {
        //alert("1");             //am not gettiig this alert
        if ( ! _alphabetSearch ) {
            return true;
        }

        if ( data[0].charAt(0) === _alphabetSearch ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    } );
```

Comment: dataTable isn't defined..

Comment: where is `_alphabetSearch` variable defined? can you please reproduce this on jsfiddle?

Comment: put `_alphabetSearch` and `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push` inside `document.ready` and try. Put variable in first line.

Comment: no...still  not working